# Android Button shows in graphical layout but not on device

Tags: android

I have been trying to display two buttons on an Android app. However, the buttons are not visible and the whole page is a blank. This is my XML code-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.cameracapture.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Capture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="Capture"
        android:text="@string/capture" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Upload"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="Upload"
        android:text="@string/upload" />
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/Display"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/upload"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I view the above code in the Graphical Layout, it shows the buttons perfectly. So, I guess that means it's not an issue of `match_parent` or `wrap_content`. I even tried to see if introducing a text view would make a difference. Again, it showed up on the Graphical Layout perfectly but on my device, only a blank screen is visible.
Could it be a problem of my device, instead of the code?

P.S. The device I am using is Motorola Moto G, which has a 4.5 inches display.

EDIT: the XML file is named fragment_main. Here's my JAVA code.
    package com.example.cameracapture;

```
import java.io.File;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.provider.MediaStore;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

    public void Capture(View view){

        // create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "DCIM/Camera");
        imagesFolder.mkdirs();
        File image = new File(imagesFolder, "image_001.jpg");
        Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);// create a file to save the image
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage); // set the image file name

        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    public void Upload(View view){

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/DCIM/Camera/image_001.jpg"; 
        File imgFile = new File(path);
        if(imgFile.exists())
    {
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());                  
            ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Display);
            myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    }
        else                    
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"no IMAGE IS PRESENT'",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }


}
```

Comment: maybe you are changing visibility programmatically?

Comment: post the activity code where you have referenced this layout. Also, state the name of your layout xml

Comment: check to see if you are changing visibility of button in onCreate method.

Comment: Unless you post your Java file, it is not possible for the SO to help you. As far as your XML goes, it looks fine.

Comment: what is the name of this `layout file`.. i thing this layout inflated under the placement holder...so may be that is the issue..

Comment: Did you refer to the right layout in the setContentView()-Method in your Activity? It would be more easier do find the issue, when you show  us the onCreate-Method of your Activity ;)

Comment: I've edited my question to include the Java file too.

Comment: You are not initializing the components (buttons and ImageView) properly in your java code., hence the issue. Please see below my answer which has proper initialization and use that code in your file..that should resolve.

Comment: @Deathstroke - Please see my latest code in the response. As per my earlier comment, updated the code for you. It works perfectly without issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xml file is never being used.

The `setContentView()` for your activity contains `activity_main`.

Check your layout `activity_main` - set a button inside and run the code as it is, you will see that button.

What you want is to set `fragment_main`.

One way to do it is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity //or ActionBarActivity--considering it extends activity
{
        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 
        if (savedInstanceState == null) 
        {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
 
        public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment 
    {
 
        public PlaceholderFragment() 
        {
        }
 
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);//here is your fragment layout 
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

Further ref:
1. [Example: sample default](http://atmarkplant.com/android-fragment-first/)
2. [Multi pane development: fragments](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html)
3. [How to work with fragments - android](http://mrbool.com/how-to-work-with-fragments-in-android-applications/28259)

Comment: Yes, that did it!!
Thank you so much. Really appreciate it.

Comment: you are welcome, glad it helped you. ..do go through the reference links to help you understand it better

Answer (score 0):

From your responses it looks like you are referring to the wrong layout file. Hence I'm putting my code here assuming that your XML is `'fragment_main.xml`. This is my MainActivity.java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
static Button capture;
static Button upload;
static ImageView Display;
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

public void Capture(View view){

    // create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "DCIM/Camera");
    imagesFolder.mkdirs();
    File image = new File(imagesFolder, "image_001.jpg");
    Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);// create a file to save the image
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage); // set the image file name

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}

public void Upload(View view){

    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/DCIM/Camera/image_001.jpg"; 
    File imgFile = new File(path);
    if(imgFile.exists())
{
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());                  
        Display.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
}
    else                    
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"no IMAGE IS PRESENT'",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        capture = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Capture);
        upload = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Upload);
        Display = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Display);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

and below is the screen shot how it looks on the emulator and executes perfectly. [image]

Comment: Yes, that's probably it. I didn't use the Layout Inflater. 
One tiny issue is still there, if you could bear with me.
On including
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
I get the error statement 

The method add(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, 
 MainActivity.PlaceholderFragment).

How do I correct that?

Comment: Cool, please accept it as the answer and vote up. Thank You and Welcome to Android Programming.

Comment: I can't upvote it. I need atleast 15 reputation. Sorry.

Comment: But you can accept it as the answer meanwhile. Later when you get 15+, you can upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity class - need to add setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_xml)
where "your_layout_xml" is the xml file you are working on. This may fix the problem.
Also, check "tools:context="com.example.cameracapture.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" line that you are supplying the proper path/context here